# Nginx + Gunicorn + Django - nginx not allowing static files

Tags: nginx, configuration, python, django, gunicorn

Updated Code - this is still not working though.

**Settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**nginx conf :: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite**

```
server {
        server_name ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com;
        access_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/error/access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/error/error.log warn;
        connection_pool_size 2048;

        location /static/ {
            #alias /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/static/;
            #alias /static/;
            root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
            #proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
    }
```

**gunicorn config -**

```
command = '/usr/local/bin/gunicorn'
logfile = "/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/error/gunicorn.log"
loglevel = "info"
pythonpath = '/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite'
bind = '127.0.0.1:8001'
```

**full path to img dir and css dir:**

```
/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/static/css
/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/static/img
```

**Receiving an error in the error.log:**

```
001/favicon.ico", host: "ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
2013/09/02 16:57:42 [error] 2819#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8001/", host: "ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
```

Anything that is glaringly wrong? I'm still getting a 404 error on both img and css files when I try to view them through the outputted html source.

Comment: The configuration seems fine to me, does the file `/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/img/templated/base/LogoV1.png` actually exist ?

Comment: No it doesn't. /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/static/img/templated/base/LogoV1.png does . This is missing the `static` dir after `homelaunch` dir . So what do I have to modify? If you could please specify in an answer I will try it out

Comment: Does `STATIC_ROOT = '/mysite/homelaunch/'` have to change to: `STATIC_ROOT = '/mysite/homelaunch/static/'` ?

Comment: additionally, i tried this as well ^^  and it didnt fix anything. It ALWAYS loads the template, but will not load the static files: img, css, etc .

Comment: yeah I've run this portion of it already too

Comment: Okay, I fixed that. Code updated. it seems to be definitely throwing a http404 error now when i click the on css link within the html source outputted - it didnt before, butStill no images or css working though. I also verified that '/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/static/' is accessible and it is. Any thought?

Comment: I'm getting an error in error.log as specified in nginx config of:
2013/09/01 03:33:37 [alert] 2689#0: accept4() failed (24: Too many open files) - any idea? . I also just turned on DEBUG in settings.py - nothing new at least on output

Comment: This error is potentially unrelated to the problem i am having

Comment: DEBUG is turned on. I get the basic 404 page served by django. It throws an error with the urls.py . It says it can't find a path to use for http://ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8001/static/img/templated/base/LogoV1.png , do I have to specify a regex for all of these directories, like: /img/templated/base/, /img/templated/home in urls.py? To serve all of the directories for static files?

Comment: am I missing any required settings on nginx that you can think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer has been edited to summarize the solutions.*

### In the configuration of nginx

Replacing:

```
alias /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/;
```

with:

```
root /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/;
```

According to the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias): "When location matches the last part of the directive’s value...it is better to use the root directive instead"

Replacing:

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

with:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

### In gunicorn's config

Replacing:

```
bind = 'ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8001'
```

with:

```
bind = '127.0.0.1:8001'
```

### In django's settings

Setting `STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/static/'` which is the correct absolute filesystem path.

Setting `DEBUG = True` to have more detailed error information.

Comment: yes and gunicorn

Comment: yes it does ! This is so weird ha

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I tried testing this, but nothing has changed the img and css are not appearing. I updated my question with even more detail - could you see if you see if anything is wrong ? I'm going to try look at the documentation some more myself. Thank you for your help thus far !

Comment: gunicorn conf is updated above - now my site isn't loading lol.

Comment: Does this tell you anything?

Comment: Once you change gunicorn's `bind` value you have to use the right URL: `http://ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com/` not `http://ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8001/`

Comment: DUDE!!!!!!! This is working now. You are da-bomb! Can I treat you to a starbucks?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
location /static/ {
            alias /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/;
        }
```

For this one:

```
location /static/ {
            alias  /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/static/;
}
```

If you do a alias you need put absolute path, because you have defined static dir on settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

So if you  put alias this dir /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/;

Nginx think the statics files are on /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/ and not in  /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/static

Sorry for my bad english, i try to improve :(

I hope you understand me.

Comment: This does the same thing as replacing `alias` by `root`, so it won't help more than my answer.

Comment: Not is the same, because on django he have defindes satatic files on /static/ so if change alias for correct dir stil work, he have alias defines for orther dir not for statics:

location /static/ {
            alias /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/;
        }

So this solution is if he have their statics on /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/statics

Comment: @Skamasle - please see updated code and give your thoughts. I would really appreciate it

Comment: So and now working ?

May point is only than you need define the alias on same dir when you have statics.., so I hope that works if not give us some lines of your error logs, and your dir distribution so what are on /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/homelaunch/ and on /home/ubuntu/virtualenv/mysite/ and on what dir you have your statics etc

I have a django setup for some of my clients whit similar alias, and work very well.

Comment: @Skamasle - what do you need from me?

Comment: So you still have the problem whit images ?
give us your error log, last lines on paste bin, and give us also path dir when you have your static content, your images or template.